# Can't deploy contract (Substrate) system.ExtrinsicFailed Other

Tags: substrate, polkadot, rust-ink

I downloaded the smart contract from the Ink repository (erc20) build it, and build metadata. After which I downloaded it, and when I try to deploy, I get such an error: [image: CHange image]

Logs from the browser console

> sendExtrinsic:: {"args":["10.000M Unit","500,000","0x3e1d2b076ae57e296098e162294676e3ff41baa7bc0b78c0b8a826393775169d","0x5ebd88d600000000000000000000000000000000"],"callIndex":"0x1103","method":"instantiate","section":"contracts"}
>   main.a12dd3e8.js:351 makeExtrinsicCall: extrinsic :: 0xad0284ff8eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a480142424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242760008001103130000e8890423c78a82841e003e1d2b076ae57e296098e162294676e3ff41baa7bc0b78c0b8a826393775169d505ebd88d600000000000000000000000000000000
>   main.a12dd3e8.js:351 makeExtrinsicCall: updated status :: {"events":[],"status":{"Ready":null}}
>   main.a12dd3e8.js:351 makeExtrinsicCall: updated status :: {"events":[{"phase":{"ApplyExtrinsic":2},"event":{"index":"0x0c06","data":[1375382416168]},"topics":[]},{"phase":{"ApplyExtrinsic":2},"event":{"index":"0x0001","data":[{"Other":null},{"weight":500000,"class":"Normal","paysFee":"Yes"}]},"topics":[]}],"status":{"InBlock":"0x2deed44e09a1552c2b1594515d01e64a5f3753085b34a7dbd889ed5036c873e6"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PR to fix this. https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/2873

The PR https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/5712 introduced breaking changes and the UI can't handle this changes until https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/2604 gets resolved.

Comment: I have a similar issue with deploying example contract-transfer. I am building the contract on rc4.